# How to get parent node in Stanford's JavaNLP?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, nlp, stanford-nlp

Suppose I have such chunk of a sentence:

```
(NP
      (NP (DT A) (JJ single) (NN page))
      (PP (IN in)
        (NP (DT a) (NN wiki) (NN website))))
```

At a certain moment of time I have a reference to `(JJ single)` and I want to get the `NP` node binding `A single page`. If I get it right, that `NP` is the parent of the node, `A` and `page` are its siblings and it has no children (?). When I try to use the `.parent()` method of a tree, I *always* get null. The API says that's because the implementation doesn't know how to determine the parent node. Another method of interest is `.ancestor(int height, Tree root)`, but I don't know how to get the root of the node. In both cases, since the parser knows how to indent and group trees, it must know the "parent" tree, right? How can I get it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Tree` itself will never return the parent of the node, since it's hardcoded in the `Tree` sources. Meanwhile `TreeGraphNode` overrides that method and works well. Changing a Tree to a TreeGraphNode is as easy as

```
TreeGraphNode sentence = new TreeGraph(tree).root();
```

Comment: @dmcer - fine, so there is the `sentence.transform(transformer)` method, there is separate transformer class and another one that initiates transformation. *Where* do you suggest to keep the current root?

Comment: @dmcer - in the transform method I'm overriding, I need to know the parent of the current tree that is being transformed. Since the only parameter of the transform method is the tree, how do I get the parent of that tree? That is, I want to use root while transforming, not after

Comment: @dmcer - it is applied `traversed in a depth-first, left-to-right order, and the TreeTransformer is called on each node`. To transform a tree I need info about its parent. This way I can hold all code processing certain trees in one place. You suggest moving this code to the code, processing all possible parents of all nodes?

Comment: I think this probably isn't worth arguing over. Yes, it is possible to just make sure that all the `Tree` objects you're transforming are actually instances of `TreeGraph` so that you can call `parent()`. However, you will end up with a `TreeTransformer` that **throws a `RuntimeException`/`NullPointerException` exception if someone else mistakenly gives it a regular `Tree` object**. Could you edit the question and this answer to mention `TreeTransformer` and the issues with using `Tree.transform`? Maybe also add what sort of operation you are performing on the trees.

Comment: Can you add some more information? If I have iterated through a tree and am at a node `tree`, I can create a `TreeGraphNode` according to your code. However, when I called `sentence.parent()`, I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: I dont think any of these methods work, they either give null or an exception of unsupportedoperationexception ..... @Fluffy can you give full code example here?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a reference to the root of the tree, then you can use method `parent(Tree root)` to get the parent of any node in the tree. Assume that the tree root is referred to as `root`, and that the JJ node is referred to as `jjTree`, then `jjTree.parent(root)` will return the parent NP node.

Comment: Thanks bro, now I can finally continue writing my script